# What if the db size exceeds memory in sqlite?

Tags: database, sqlite, memory-management

I'm working with a heavy dataset, which I chose to store in plain binary format and load into memory in chunks. However, even the smallest chunk is about to exceed my computer memory (16GB), so i'll have to fragment them further or find another solution. The whole dataset is around half a terabyte.

I've seen on wiki that sqlite can work with up to 32TB of data, which is cool. However, I could not figure out whether you have to have 32TB of memory to use it, or you can have smaller memory and store the thing on a  hard drive. My understanding is that it should be possible, I need very simple operations like add line, read line, pick all lines with a given value e.t.c

I would appreciate if you folks help me, because I would hate to invest into studying sqlite only to learn that it does not work the way I thought. Also if you have any insight that you think might help, please share.

Comment: You should be fine. sqlite automatically manages memory for you by only loading the parts of the db that it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases, including SQLite, can work on the data in chunks, i.e., they need to load only a single record into memory at once. (But using more memory for caching makes things much faster.) Furthermore, if intermediate data becomes too large, it can be moved into [temporary files](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html). This is the default behaviour, so it is not explicitly advertized.

Having the entire database in memory [is possible](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), but would make sense only for temporary data that is not to be saved anyway.